# Remove white space from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am populating my datagrid and did some styling on the DataGrid. I keep getting white space on the left side of the DataGrid. I've tried to set paddings and margins to 0 and still get the white space. I've attached a screenshot below. Please advice how to get rid of that white space.

[image: 1]

XAML Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!-- DataGrid style -->
        <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderStyle1}"/>
            <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource CellStyle1}"/>
        </Style>
        <!-- DataGridColumnHeader style -->
        <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="27"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#191919"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Cyan"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,2,2,2"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="CellStyle1" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333333"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.1"/>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="auto" Width="auto" MaxHeight="400" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Is this in a browser, an app, other? Can you inspect it with an inspection tool? Have you set Canvas.Left to 0 and tested it there?

Comment: Remove: Canvas.Left="10"

Comment: @lem2802 Have tried removing Canvas.Left and tried removing canvas altogether and still same result.

Comment: @EBrown It is an app.

Comment: @Trevor_zam How are you viewing it? Are you able to inspect the HTML elements? Have you tried setting the <Grid> to have no margin or padding?

Comment: @EBrown I am viewing it from visual studio. Grid is set to default. Checked the properties and they are at 0.

Comment: @Trevor_zam And it looks wrong on the device itself? Have you checked it on the device (or VM) itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The stuff you can see are called row headers.

You can remove them by setting their width to 0.

Add this to the `Datagrid` style:

```
<Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
```